# errors in fields not displaying on Django admin form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a Django admin form which has an known source of errors that prevent the form from being saved. I have checked all the fields in the model, and all the required fields have been filled out. Nevertheless, I continue to get the standard error message:

```
Please correct the error below.
```

at the top of the form, yet no fields are highlighted with an error message.

What can be another cause, and how do I debug this?

Answer (score 12):

Here is how you can see what the hidden errors are. Above your form class (create one if it doesn't already exist), add these imports:

```
# get a way to log the errors:
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# convert the errors to text
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
```

Then add to your form class this def:

```
class MyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def is_valid(self):
        log.info(force_text(self.errors))
        return super(MyAdminForm, self).is_valid()
```

When you examine your log after submitting again, it will list all the hidden errors.

When I had this problem, I found the cause of the errors were some 'calculated' read-only fields that I had added to the form, e.g.:

```
get_num_items = forms.IntegerField()
```

The validation failed since these fields had no value as required. Changing the field definition to include required=False fixed the problem:

```
get_num_items = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
```

Comment: To add to the possible causes - I had this error when including inlines with a custom template which overwrote the fields to show only some extra, but read-only, info. I fixed it by listing the fields explicitly as read-only fields, so the view logic knew not to expect them.

Comment: Thanks for this Scott, I had declared two required fields, password1 and password2 under `forms.py`, but had  `add_fieldsets = ((None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),`, so I needed to change it `add_fieldsets = ((None, {'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}))` under the django admin page.  Errors couldn't show up for field 'password' at first

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me, it was a DateTimeField with auto_now_add which I force the value in the database, but the format was not considered correct for Django and because the fields marked with auto_now_add are not shown in the admin, neither the error is shown.